# Chained array creator

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

Just for fun, I'm looking for a way to create a function, `array`, with the following behavior:

```
array()       // []
array(2)      // ugly function thing
array(2)()    // [2]
array(2)(3)() // [2,3] etc
```

The closest I can come is

```
function array(x) {
    if (x == null)
        return []
    return function() {
        // same as above?!
        // I don't want some inelegant solution involving a lot of additional parameters
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in ECMA5? If not, prove that the syntax can't accomodate such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "*same as above*". This is solved by a "recursive"<sup>1</sup> call:

```
function makeArrayAppender(arr) {
    return function array() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        if (!args.length)
            return arr;
        else
            return makeArrayAppender(arr.concat(args));
    };
}
var array = makeArrayAppender([]);
```

<sub>1: As the function is called from the returned "thunk" function, not from the call itself, it's not really recursive. It's more like a tail-call-optimised function, being invoked manually in-a-row without filling the stack</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do exactly what you are looking for. The self-executing function scopes off `r` and `rr`, which are basically static variables using this implementation. Of course, you need to reset `r` after assigning it to `rr`, so you can return the Array when `ra` has an `undefined` argument, which then stops the recursive behavior.

```
var array = (function(){
  var r = [], rr;
  function ra(a){
    if(a === undefined){
      rr = r; r = []
      return rr;
    }
    else{
      r.push(a);
      return ra;
    }
  }
  return ra;
})();
console.log(array()); console.log(array(5)()); console.log(array());
console.log(array(7)(2)());
```

Comment: `array(2)(3)()` does not satisfy the test case (`[2, 3]`).

Comment: Also, after `array(1); array(2);` the call `array()` will return `[1,2]` instead of the empty array.

Comment: The problem is that `array(1) == array` and `array(1)() == array()`. Can you spot where this comes from?

Comment: I believe it's fixed now.